# Android Auto program on Google Play gave a Provisional Pass For My Application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I am uploading 4 Apk of my VoIP Application in Alpha Close Testing. After one day I got a mail about **We're not able to test your app for Auto functionality without two test login account. Please respond back to this email with a second test account login information and submit your app for re-review through your Play Console**. after I reply to my Login Credential and submit app again. on the next day, I have received the same mail from Google and another thing is that my application status show **Published** in my Play Console Account.

Now, I got another mail from google **At this time please make the appropriate edits to your app and resubmit, or you can upload a new APK in your Play Console. After you click Submit, our team will review your app again to make sure it meets our guidelines for creating apps for Android Auto**

Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the Screenshot of received mail from Google]

This is my app.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group = 'com.github.jitpack'

configurations {
    playstoreCompile
    freeCompile
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v8a", "x86", "mips"
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'x86': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'//url 'https://jitpack.io'
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://jitpack.io'
            }
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    productFlavors {
        free
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'NamespaceTypo', 'MissingTranslation', 'RestrictedApi', 'InvalidPackage', 'MissingQuantity', 'AppCompatResource'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            aaptOptions {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':alphabetsindexfastscrollrecycler')
    compile project(':android-support-v4-preferencefragment')
    compile project(path: ':app:libs:MemorizingTrustManager')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.0v1.5.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.intellij', module: 'annotations'
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.realm-browser:library:0.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.realm-browser:library:0.0.3'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.blennerSilva:AwesomeDialog:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:1.1'
    implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:openpgp-api:10.0'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:1.52'
    implementation 'org.jitsi:org.otr4j:0.22'
    implementation 'org.gnu.inet:libidn:1.15'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.2.1'
    implementation 'de.measite.minidns:minidns-hla:0.2.4'
    implementation 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.3.4'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.2.8'
    implementation 'org.whispersystems:signal-protocol-java:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'net.ypresto.androidtranscoder:android-transcoder:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'net.bohush.geometricprogressview:geometricprogressview:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:2.9.30'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.1.0'
    implementation 'q.rorbin:badgeview:1.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    freeCompile 'com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.twilio:video-android:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.ebanx:swipe-button:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp"> 

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="net.ypresto.androidtranscoder, android.support.v4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" /> 
    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_useSip"
        android:label="@string/permlab_useSip"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_configureSip"
        android:label="@string/permlab_configureSip"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" /> 

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".CrashApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:backupAgent=".backup.SipBackupAgent"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:value="false"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        tools:replace="android:label, android:supportsRtl">
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_type"
            android:value="nightly" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="app_channel"
            android:value="trunk" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
            android:value="true" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.receiver.RestartSipServiceBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sipStack">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.service.RestartService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".ui.view.java.contactsyncadapter.common.accounts.GenericAccountService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/contact_sync_authenticator" />
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.DeviceStateReceiver"
            android:permission="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
            android:process=":sipStack">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.accounts.activate" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.OutgoingCall"
            android:process=":sipStack">
            <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".ui.PrivilegedOutgoingSipCallBroadcaster"
            android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
            android:targetActivity=".ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sip" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".ui.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster"
            android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/sip_call"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:permission="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
            android:targetActivity=".ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias> 
        <receiver
            android:name=".plugins.telephony.CallHandler"
            android:process=":sipStack">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.phone.action.HANDLE_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.receiver.DynamicCallState"
            android:permission="android.permission.USE_SIP"
            android:process=":sipStack">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.service.CALL_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider
            android:name=".service.PreferenceProvider"
            android:authorities="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.prefs"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
        <provider
            android:name=".db.DBProvider"
            android:authorities="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.db"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP"
            android:process=":sipStack" />
        <provider
            android:name=".db.HistoryStatusProvider"
            android:authorities="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp"
            android:process=":sipStack" />
        <provider
            android:name=".ui.view.java.contactsyncadapter.provider.FeedProvider"
            android:authorities="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.contactsyncadapter"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name=".plugins.codecs.ReceiverOpus">
            <meta-data
                android:name="lib_name"
                android:value="libpj_opus_codec.so" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="init_factory"
                android:value="pjmedia_codec_opus_init" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.codecs.action.REGISTER_CODEC" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <receiver
            android:name=".plugins.codecs.ReceiverG729"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="lib_name"
                android:value="libpj_g729_codec.so" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="init_factory"
                android:value="pjmedia_codec_g729_init" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.codecs.action.REGISTER_CODEC" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.phone.action.DIALER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sip" />
                <data android:scheme="csip" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.phone.action.CALLLOG" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.phone.action.FAVORITES" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="xxx.com.xxxxx.mobileapp.phone.action.MESSAGES" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ui.view.chat.eu.siacs.conversations.services.XmppConnectionService" />
        <receiver android:name=".ui.view.chat.eu.siacs.conversations.services.EventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
                <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
                android:value=".services.ContactChooserTargetService" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".ui.view.chat.eu.siacs.conversations.services.ExportLogsService" />
        <service
            android:name=".ui.view.chat.eu.siacs.conversations.services.ContactChooserTargetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.quickblox.messages.TYPE"
            android:value="GCM" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.quickblox.messages.SENDER_ID"
            android:value="@string/sender_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.quickblox.messages.QB_ENVIRONMENT"
            android:value="DEVELOPMENT" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <service android:name=".Updated.VideoCall.activity.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Updated.VideoCall.activity.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name=".ui.view.chat.eu.siacs.conversations.services.BarcodeProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.barcodes"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Help will be Appreciated,

Comment: Did you provide 2 accounts to them or one? And I see two apks, does both apk's work with same account?

Comment: @TheAnkush yes I provided two accounts and I am using split APK with the same account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. [See meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561)

Comment: My question is regarding the app published time I faced some issue to upload Application.so please don't give a close vote for @Zoe. Thanks.

Comment: This sort of question is best addressed to Google Play Support.

Comment: Yes, @NickFortescue i am also chat with play support but i didn't get any resolution for that.